# Как работе for c let?

Tags: javascript, node.js, frontend, ecmascript-6, замыкания

Если написать вот так:

```js
for (let i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
  setTimeout(() => console.log(i), 1000);
}
```

То будет выведено **0, 1, 2** , а не **3, 3, 3**, как в случаи с var. Исходя из результатов этого примера, видно, что для каждой из функций в setTimeout в замыкании хранится своё i т.е логично предлоположить, что на каждой итерации цикла for создаётся своя переменная итаратор i.

Но если написать вот так:

```js
var prev = null;
for (let i = {j: 0}; i.j < 3; ++i.j) {
  if (!prev) {
     prev = i;
  } else {
    console.log(prev == i);
    prev = i;
  }
}
```

здесь уже было бы логично ожидать, что оба раза будет **false**, ведь из предыдучего примера сделали вывод, что на каждой итерации цикла, i будет пересоздано, а значит будет уже отличать по ссылке от объекта сохранённого в prev. Но на самом деле оба раза напичатает **true**

**Подскажите, пожалуйста, как так получается?**

**Если i не пересоздаётся на каждой итерации, то почему в замыкании у каждой функции в замыкании оказывается свой i?**

Comment: Попробую предположить, что в обоих случаях ничего никогда не пересоздаётся, а просто внутри замыкания сохраняется текущее состояние переменной `i`. В случае с числами каждое число является отдельным объектом (точнее, примитивом, но сейчас это не так важно), поэтому и получается как будто эффект пересоздания. Но в случае с объектом вы нигде не помещаете в переменную `i` новый объект, и при сохранении его значения в замыкании каждый раз оказывается один и тот же объект. (Но, возможно, я объяснил коряво, сейчас придёт Grundy и расскажет как положено :)

Comment: Другими словами, `++i` создаёт новый объект (новое число), а `++i.j` не создаёт, а редактирует существующий, поэтому в замыкании он и остаётся. Если вы создадите новый объект, написав `i={j:i.j+1}`, то получите `false`.

Answer (score 0):

Ниже пример когда выведется два раза `false`. У Вас выводится true потому что идёт присвоение по ссылке. prev = i значит что в переменной prev будет ссылка на переменную i.
В результате на новом этапе цикла после увеличения значения j, в переменной prev оно так же увеличится, в результате при сравнении выводится `true`

```js
var prev = null;
for (let i = {j: 0}; i.j < 3; ++i.j) {
  if (!prev) {
     prev = {...i};
  } else {
    console.log(prev == i);
    prev = {...i};
  }
}
```